# How can I do breadcrumbs bootstrap with arrow look and feel?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on MVC 5 project, there I have to create **Electrical > Lighting > HT&LT..** with respect to click.

Example: If the user click on **Lighting**, then show like **Electrical > Lighting** or even if click on **HT&LT** then show like **Electrical > Lighting > HT&LT** like that.

[image]

Here is a div with `idSearch-item` that I have added bootstrap breadcrumbs (hardcoded value),

```html
<div class="row" style="display:none;padding:0 0 20px 0" id="idSearch-item">
                
            </div>
```

How can I do this when click on each `a` element?

```html
<ul>   
<li class="dropdown-header">Electrical</li> 
    <li>
        <a href="#">Lighting</a>      
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">HT &amp; LT</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now It is showing **HT&LT/HT&LT** but I want to display **Electrical > Lighting > HT&LT..** inside the `idSearch-item` div if click on **HT&LT** by using below code.

```js
$("li a").each(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {           
            document.getElementById("idSearch-item").innerHTML = '<ul class="breadcrumb"><li><a href="#">' + $(this).text() + '</a></li><li>' + $(this).text() + '</li></ul>';
            $('#idSearch-item').show();
        });
    });
```

How can I do this ?

Please help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve a 'breadcrumbs' effect by creating a class (in this case `.more`)  which you animate on click, to show/hide the visibility of the children:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#collapse li").children('ul').hide();
  $("#collapse li").on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideToggle(350);
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
#collapse .more {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -1em;
}

#collapse .more:before {
  content: "+";
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#collapse .more ul {
  text-indent: 0em;
  cursor: initial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="collapse">
  <li>Top-level without children
  <li class="more">Top-level with children
    <ul>
      <li>Sub-level without children</li>
      <li class="more">Sub-level with children
        <ul>
          <li>Child 1</li>
          <li>Child 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The styling itself comes from the `:before` psuedo-selector's `content`. Just use the greater-than sign:

```
#collapse .more:before {
  content: ">";
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Simply adjust to insert it how you'd like :)

Hope this helps! :)

**EDIT**:

To have it update the title on click, all you need to do is change the `innerHTML` based on the `text()` of the element that was clicked:

```js
$("li").on("click", "a", function() {
  document.getElementById("idSearch-item").innerHTML = $(this).text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="idSearch-item">HEADER</div>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown-header">Electrical</li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Lighting</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">HT &amp; LT</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Excuse me...(apology) Actually I want just show clicked each above items looking like breadcrumb's Electrical > Lighting > HT&LT.. inside this div `idSearch-item`. How can I do this ?

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I slightly misunderstood. For that, you just need to replace the `innerHTML` with the text from the click. I'll update my answer to cover that :)

Comment: No problem; I've just updated my answer -- hopefully this is what you're looking for :)

Comment: Now I want to display each `a` text based on click (eg: Electrical > Lighting > HT&LT..). I have updated my question. How can I do this ?

Comment: Your edit asks for something different to the original question, meaning you are now [**asking multiple questions at once**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223). Please [**ask a new question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) rather than updating your existing question. If it helps, you can link to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690096) for reference. This solution was marked as correct, and if someone stumbled across this question, they may think that this solution also covers the edit. I'm happy to help with your new question once posted :)