# Putting several links in a line contained in a wrapper

Tags: html, css

I am doing a drop down menu and i want the drop down items to all be in a line and probably drops to the next line on screen resolution. my html is

**HTML**

```
  <li class="main"><a href="#"> Menu </a>
    <ul>
     <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">
        <div class="content" style="width:300px;">
          <img src="image.jpg"><p>text</p>  
        </div></a>
      </li>

    <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <img src="image.jpg"><p>text</p>  
        </div></a>
      </li>    

   </ul>
 </li>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {float:left; display:inline-block; width:auto}

.sub-menu{float:left; width:300px;}

.content{width:100%}
```

What I am targeting is when someone clicks the main menu "***menu***" it drops down to the sub menu "***sub-menu***" and all sub menus come in line until screen width changes and the last one automatically goes to a next line. Any help will be much appreciated people!!!

Thanks in advance.

**Michelle**

Comment: Your sub-menus have content in them that consists of both text and images. I take it these are supposed to display below the 'menu chain'? So **only** the 'text' from the menu is shown inline? You may find it easier to create a 'pure' secondary menu, that consists of only the bread-crumbed `<a>` text that you wish to display.

Comment: Remove the paragraph tags

Comment: @Obsidian: Thanks man but yeah thats the reason, I wanted the sub menus to have contents in them as well, its like a drop down box with images to the left and some few text at the right. The good thing is that they wil all have the same items, sort of a dupplicate but with different names in the <p> tags and images

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little confused as to exactly how you want it to display. Are you looking for something like [**the first example here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44690228/2341603), where you have multiple sub-items which are indented, with different bullet point styles? Or are you looking for standard bullet points with a small image next to the bullet point, and text next to the image, all displayed inline? Perhaps something like the [**BootStrap Navbar Template**](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/), which expands links 'down', and completely changes display for mobile devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little hard to understand, but from what I'm guessing, you want to click the main menu, and a sub menu drops down, displaying the contents (img with text).

This might be what you're looking for:

```
<style>
 .main {background-color: red;}

 .sub-menu {background-color: blue;}
 .sub-menu a {display: inline-block; color: white;}
</style>

<div class="main">
 <a href="#"> Menu </a>
</div>

<div class="sub-menu">
  <a href="#"> <img src="image.jpg"> text </a>

  <a href="#"> <img src="image.jpg"> text </a>
</div>
```

Where you can make the sub-menu hidden until you click the main menu. You might also want to add some padding to the links for spacing. Colors are there so you can see the layout.

`<p>` elements automatically drop a line in web display, making them display below the `img` tags.